# How To add Auto Increment in module default ID fields Suit CRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

Is it possible to add auto increment in module default  ID field in **Suite CRM**. ID field contains *36 char* type.

Is there any settings options available in **SuiteCRM** ?

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is any option/setting regarding this in admin, if you are making custom module programmatically, then this can be possible, I never tried.

Comment: @Bhaskar Thanks for replay, 
I have make custom modules and I want to add auto increment in ID field.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the goal of auto-incrmenting fields is usually to create a human-friendly ID field, e.g. Case ID, Quote ID, Account Number. This is different than the CRM system's GUID, though both are effectively unique identifiers. It's is simply that the human-friendly ID field is easier to communicate with colleagues ("Hey Jim, bring up account 1505" is easier than "bring up account 6ccd780c-baba-1026-9564-5b8c656024db").

With that in mind, the goal here is to add a new integer field entirely, and ensure that it auto-increments. SugarCRM supports auto-incrementing **integer** fields out-of-the-box, but it is a code level customization. This is not applicable to the default **id** field, since this is a varchar field.

Let's look at the Professional edition's Quote field "Quote Number" as an example,

The vardef is thus defined in `modules/Quotes/vardefs.php`:

```
<?php
$dictionary['Quote']['fields'][] = 
    'quote_num' => array(
        'name' => 'quote_num',
        'vname' => 'LBL_QUOTE_NUM',
        'type' => 'int',
        'auto_increment' => true,
        'readonly' => true,
        'required' => true,
        'unified_search' => true,
        'full_text_search' => array('enabled' => true, 'boost' => 3),
        'disable_num_format' => true,
        'enable_range_search' => true,
        'options' => 'numeric_range_search_dom',
    );
```

The vardefs further define an index to set the auto-increment feature in the database level:

```
<?php
$dictionary['Quote']['indices'][] = 
    array(
        'name' => 'quote_num',
        'type' => 'unique',
        'fields' => array('quote_num', 'system_id')
    );
```

Note that the index for your custom field will probably not need the `system_id` reference, it is more typical to definite it as simply `'fields' => array('quote_num')`

Another out-of-the-box example is in the Cases module with the field `case_number`. It also employs a vardef and index definition.

This strategy can be extracted to a new custom field on any out-of-box or custom module. One would define both the field and the index in `custom/Extension/modules/MyModule/Ext/Vardefs/customfield.php`. Note that when using the Extension framework, Studio will create a field in this directory like `sugarfield_myfield.php` and it would be best to not define your vardef in the same file, because Studio will overrite them. Further, it is best to not define conflicts in your file that Studio may attempt to generate, or else one change or the other will be overridden. Define in `customfield.php` only what is necessary to accomplish your goal, and format the array such that it does not entirely re-define itself when the code is executed, e.g.

```
 $dictionary['Quote']['fields']['quote_num']['auto_increment'] = true;
 $dictionary['Quote']['fields']['quote_num']['disable_num_format'] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I have implemented auto-increment fields in SuiteCRM is like this:

- Create custom field of type `TextField` by using SuiteCRM Studio. For example add the field `product_number` to the module `Products`. This will create the field `product_number_c` in the database table `aos_products_cstm`. The field should **not** be required.
- Remove the newly created field `product_number` from the EditView of the module `Products`.
- In your database, create the table `product_number_seq`, that has only the field `id`, which is an auto-increment field. The name `product_number_seq` can be changed to whatever you prefer.
- Create trigger on the table `aos_products_cstm`:

  ```
  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER product_number_insert
  BEFORE INSERT ON aos_products_cstm
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO product_number_seq VALUES (NULL);
    SET NEW.product_number_c = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  END
  ```

If you do this, before every insert on the table `aos_products_cstm`, the trigger will make an insert to the table `product_number_seq` and provide `NULL` as value, so the next int will be inserted (because it is an auto-increment field). Then it will set the field `product_number_c` of the record that is being inserted in `aos_products_cstm`, to the result of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` - which will be the recently inserted value to `product_number_seq`.

It is obviously hack, so you might not prefer it, but I have used it and it works.