# How to add auto increment in field of SuiteCRM

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am using SuiteCRM-7.11.5 on Windows. I want to create an ID Label which shows itself auto incremented in the the "Create New Task" window. If showing auto incremented is not possible I at least want it to auto increment in the mySQL database.

I've found some [question in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203152/how-to-add-auto-increment-in-module-default-id-fields-suit-crm) and on [SuiteCRM forum](https://suitecrm.com/suitecrm/forum/suitecrm-7-0-discussion/1841-how-to-add-a-autoincrement-field-for-account-and-contacts?limitstart=0#7591) (No Extension folder) which are all outdated or didn't work at all. The plugins are removed from github. Any help, hack or work around is appreciated. I am also new to suitecrm and mysql so step by step answer would be appreciated.

I also tried adding auto increment option in phpmyadmin but it throw error as

> Incorrect column specifier for column 'id'

Comment: For anyone searching for solution Go to this [forum link](https://suitecrm.com/suitecrm/forum/suitecrm-7-0-discussion/1841-how-to-add-a-autoincrement-field-for-account-and-contacts?start=15#18052) and download the free plugin and import it to the suiteCRM ([instructions](https://suitecrm.com/suitecrm/forum/suitecrm-7-0-discussion/1841-how-to-add-a-autoincrement-field-for-account-and-contacts?start=15#25655)).

Answer (score 1):

Auto Increment is definitely possible in suiteCRM, all you need to put a field using code like this.

```
 'auto_number' =>
            array(
                'name' => 'auto_number',
                'vname' => 'Serial No',
                'type' => 'int',
              'len' => 11,
              'required'=>true,
              'auto_increment' => true,
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Create int type field and create before save logic hook. Add below code,

```
global $db;
    $query = "SELECT MAX(field_name) as max_count FROM table where deleted=0";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $row = $db->fetchByAssoc($result);
    $max_number = $row['max_count'];
    if(empty($max_number)){
        $max_number = 1;
    }
    else{
        (int)$max_ticket_number++;
    }
    if(empty($bean->field_name)){
        $bean->field_name = $max_ticket_number;
    }
}
```